# C++ Class/Function interaction

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++ classes and exactly how they work, but I'm trying to figure what issues I have with this code.  What I'm trying to do is that the class handle the dice object, how many faces the die has and the value of the roll.  Then use those values later on in the code.  I know I've done something fundamentally wrong here I'm just not sure what.

The class header is:

```
class Dice {

private :
    int face ;
    int value ;

public:
    Dice()
    {
        face = 6;
    }
    Dice(int faceVal)
    {
        face = faceVal;
    }
    Dice(Dice &other) 
    {
        face = other.face;
    }
    Dice& operator=(const Dice &rhs);
    int roll() ;
    int getValue() const { return value; } 
    int getFace() const { return face; }

} ;

Dice& Dice::operator=(const Dice &rhs)
{
    face = rhs.face;
    return *this;
}

#endif
```

The functions/methods that are being used:

```
int Dice::roll()
{
srand((unsigned)time(0));
int randomNumber = 1 + rand() % 5;
value = randomNumber;
    return randomNumber;
}

int rollAll(Dice cup[], int n) 
{
    int faces = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        faces += cup[i].roll();
    return sum ;
}
```

And the entrance into them from the main function is:

```
total  = rollAll(cup,2) ;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
    (arr[i] =  cup[i].getValue());
```

Comment: If `Dice(Dice &other)` is meant to be a copy constructor, it needs to be `Dice(const Dice &other)` other.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: what problem u facing? post code for `rollAll` and `main` methods

Comment: Are you asking for a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) (working code required)? Your use of `srand` in each call to `Dice::roll` is the wrong approach, and your use of `rand` is worse if you care about proper randomness, but this is probably not what you were seeking feedback on.

Comment: @zneak - The `const` keyword is not required for the signature to be a valid copy constructor.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the standard does call it a copy constructor, but it [wouldn't make the type copy constructible](http://ideone.com/P2pvz0). This is not a bug in gcc: §17.6.3.1 says (in conjunction with Table 21) that a type must be constructible from a possibly `const` reference to be considered *CopyConstructible*.

Answer (score 0):

The glaring issue with your code is that your copy constructor and assignment operator are incorrect.  You are failing to actually *copy* the object fully, as you are missing the `value` member in the copying operations.

```
Dice(Dice &other) 
{
    face = other.face;
    // where is the `value` member?
}
```

So where is the copy of the `value` member being made?  If you miss any members during the copy, your program will be using "half-copies" masquerading as real copies.  These types of bugs, where you don't copy everything, are some of the toughest to find.

This is one reason why you should not get involved in writing copy/assignment functions unless it is absolutely required.  In your case, the compiler generated copy constructor / assignment operator will do the job correctly without you having to write one.